# The upper bound for supreme of product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am wondering if the following inequality for supreme norm holds? If not, can we have a upper bound for $||Ax||_{\infty}$? Thanks.
$$
||Ax||_{\infty} \leq||A||_{\infty}||x||_{\infty}
$$
Where A is a matrix and x is a vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the inequality does hold.

$$
||A||_{\infty} = sup_{x}\frac{||Ax||_{\infty}}{||x||_{\infty}} 
$$

by definition of $||A||_{\infty}$